# PHP DOMDocument saveHTML breaks format

Tags: php, dom

Why would this code:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($this->content, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$imgNodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');

if ($imgNodes->length > 0) {
    $inlineImage = new Image();
    $inlineImage->setPublicDir($publicDirPath);

    foreach ($imgNodes as $imgNode) {
        $inlineImage->setUri($imgNode->getAttribute('src'));
        $inlineImage->setName(basename($inlineImage->getUri()));

        if ($inlineImage->getUri() != $dstPath.$inlineImage->getName()) {
            $inlineImage->move($dstPath);

            $imgNode->setAttribute('src', $dstPath.'/'.$inlineImage->getName());                 
        }
    }

    $this->content = $doc->saveHtml();

}
```

executed on this code:

```
<p><img alt="fluid cat" src="/images/tmp/fluid-cat.jpg"></p><p><img alt="pandas" src="/images/tmp/pandas.jpg"></p>
```

result in this code:

```
<p><img alt="fluid cat" src="/images/full/2016-09/fluid-cat.jpg"><p><img alt="pandas" src="/images/full/2016-09/pandas.jpg"></p></p>
```

Why does it place both img tags inside the first p block?

Comment: Because your html sample doesn't have a root element. Libxml assumes that the first p is the root element and performs an automatic fix. It removes the "orphan" closing p tag and puts a closing tag at the "good place", i.e. at the end. To fix the problem, add a fake root element (`<div>....</div>` for example, or remove `LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED`) and extract its child nodes one by one to create the result string by concatenation.

Comment: I'm pretty sure DomDocument tries to correctly format things for HTML. Try adding a `/` at the end of your img tag to make it self closing

Comment: `loadHTML()` and `saveHTML()` are terribly broken and useless in practice. Consider using a third-party HTML parser like [html5lib-php](https://github.com/html5lib/html5lib-php) and a custom HTML-code generator.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your html sample doesn't have a root element that surrounds all. When LIBXML parses the html to build the DOM tree, it assumes that the first encountered tag is the root element. Consequence, the first tag `</p>` is seen as an orphan closing tag (because there's content after it) and is automatically removed, and a `</p>` is added at the end to close the root element.

To avoid these automatic fixes when you are working with html parts (not a whole html document), you need to add a fake root element. At the end, to produce the result string, you need to save each childnode of this fake root element. Example:

```
$html = '<p><img alt="fluid cat" src="/images/tmp/fluid-cat.jpg"></p><p><img alt="pandas" src="/images/tmp/pandas.jpg"></p>';

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML( '<div>' . $html . '</div>', LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD | LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);
#               ^-----------------^----- fake root element
$root = $doc->documentElement;

$result = '';

foreach($root->childNodes as $childNode) {
    $result .= $doc->saveHTML($childNode);
}

echo $result;
```